# Spring Boot loads all the available properties file regardless of my @TestPropertySource annotation

Tags: spring, unit-testing, spring-boot, properties

I have a *Spring Boot 1.4.3* project.
In the `test/resources` folder I have two properties file, let say
`a-test.properties` and `b-test.properties`.

The test class is annotated as follows:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@TestPropertySource(locations = "classpath:a-test.properties")
```

However, I see in my test that also the properties from `b-test.properties` are loaded (I verified this via a simple print output).

Why? How can I prevent this?

---

Example extracted from my test

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@TestPropertySource(locations = "classpath:base-test.properties", inheritProperties=false)
public class EmailServiceContextBasedTest {

    @SpyBean
    public JavaMailSender javaMailSender;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {

        System.out.println(
           ((JavaMailSenderImpl)javaMailSender).getPassword()
        );
        System.out.println(
           ((JavaMailSenderImpl)javaMailSender).getJavaMailProperties()
        );
    }


    @Test
    public void test() throws Exception {
      // do nothing
    }

}
```

where the `a-test.properties` is:

```
spring.mail.host=smtp.gmail.com
spring.mail.port=587
spring.mail.username=email@gmail.com
spring.mail.password=password
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.auth=false
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.enable=false
```

and `b-test.properties`

```
spring.mail.host=smtp.gmail.com
spring.mail.port=587
spring.mail.username=myemail@gmail.com
spring.mail.password=myPassword
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.auth=true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.enable=true
```

Comment: how are you reading the properties? Can you add some code demonstrating the behavior your are describing?

Comment: @dimitrisli yeah, sure! I attached an example

Comment: @mat_boy Please provide the output you get and the output you expect. Your example would only print password associated with one of properties files (in my case it's `a-test.properties`). So how did you verify `that also the properties from b-test.properties are loaded`?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the source of the issue.

I had in the test folder a class defined as in the following

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@PropertySource("classpath:a-test.properties")
public class TestApplication {

    public static void main(final String... args) {
        SpringApplication.run(TestApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

That was not called in the test, but I guess that was instantiated by default by Spring Boot when executing the tests in class `DefaultEmailServiceContextBasedTest` with the annotation

```
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
```

So, the issue was that I used `@PropertySource`. I don't know why, but replacing that annotation with `@TestPropertySource` solved the conflict issue.

Answer (score 5):

With `SpringBootTest` annotation it will automaticaly the spring boot application configuration regarding to the docs

> Annotation that can be specified on a test class that runs Spring Boot based tests. Provides the following features over and above the regular Spring TestContext Framework:
>
> - Uses SpringBootContextLoader as the default ContextLoader when no specific @ContextConfiguration(loader=...) is defined.
> - Automatically searches for a @SpringBootConfiguration when nested @Configuration is not used, and no explicit classes are specified.
> - Allows custom Environment properties to be defined using the properties attribute.
> - Provides support for different webEnvironment modes, including the ability to start a fully running container listening on a defined or random port.
> - Registers a TestRestTemplate bean for use in web tests that are using a fully running container.

So I suppose you load the other properties in other place, but the truth is `@TestPropertySource(locations = "classpath:a-test.properties", inheritProperties=false)` will only load the `a-test.properties` indeed.

**Here is a simple test:**

- **with `a-test.properties`**
  [image]
- **with `b-test.properties`**
  [image]

And with `@TestPropertySource` annotation, you still get the change to override the properties before the tests run with the `properties` attributes,

For you problem you can overrride it like `@TestPropertySource(locations = "classpath:b-test.properties", properties = {"spring.mail.host=smtp.gmail.com", "spring.mail.port=587", "spring.mail.username=email@gmail.com" ......})`

Answer (score 0):

Easiest to do what you need is to set profile such:

@ActiveProfiles("test")

Then simply write an application-test.properties file with the desired properties for run your test.